# how to perform a card flip animation using only javascript and css3

Tags: javascript

I've basically an  displaying a card. i want to flip it horizontally when i click on it.
The situation is:

html:

```
<img id="card0" src="card/back.png" class="myCard" />
```

javascript:

```
    $('#card0').click(function () {
        $('#card0').attr("src", cards[i].src);
    });
```

css:

```
.myCard {max-width: 18%;}
```

is it possible ?

Comment: Yes... Keyframes, do you know that??

Comment: It certainly is possible. You'll probably want to look into the CSS3 property 'perspective' (https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/perspective.html)

Comment: @EvilDevil https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html . looks intresting but... it uses 2 div, one for the front and one for the back. i've only an img tag...

Comment: @S.P. The cube in the 'Perspective 3' section (https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/perspective-03.html) only uses one html element for each face.

Comment: <section class="container">
  <div id="cube">
    <figure class="front">1</figure>
    <figure class="back">2</figure>
    <figure class="right">3</figure>
    <figure class="left">4</figure>
    <figure class="top">5</figure>
    <figure class="bottom">6</figure>
  </div>
</section>

there are 6 figure, one for each cube face.

in card flip example there are 2 figure-tag:

<section class="container">
  <div id="card">
    <figure class="front">1</figure>
    <figure class="back">2</figure>
  </div>
</section>

Comment: but i've only an IMG-tag and i actually change its source by javascript. how can i animate my card change (on mouse click)?